# Use path system environment variable in MSBuild exec task

Tags: msbuild

I'm calling an external tool to do some post processing in my build sequence using the `Exec` task in MSBuild. When I update the tool to a new version the name of the directory of the executable changes, but the directory is added to the system `PATH` variable. Is it possible to use the system `PATH` variable in MSBuild? I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PATH)\mytool.exe&quot;  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directory has been added to the `PATH` variable, I would expect that the file path would be resolved automatically. I.e. you should be able to use:

```
<Exec Command="mytool.exe"/>
```

Maybe first check if the resolution is working ok by opening up a command prompt, cd'ing to some root directory that is different to where the 'mytool.exe' lives, and see if it is resolved when you simply enter "mytool.exe" at the prompt.

Comment: Thanks I just found out as well :) I was a bit confused because I had to use `$(PROGRAMFILES)` before so I thought there was a `$(PATH)` as well.